# Discord.js Reaction roles not working with custom emojis

Tags: discord.js

I have been trying to create a reaction role giver with custom emojis. It works with normal discord emojis but when i try it with the custom ones it doesn't give me the role. I have the unicodes and they show up and i don't get any error messages it just doesn't give me the role. Thanks for every help. Here's the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = '996702836249346119';
        const omegaRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "ω");
        const omega0Role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "ω₀");
        const omega1Role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "ω₁");

        const omegaEmoji = '<:Waaa:996350040912183358>';
        const omega0Emoji = '<a:fendi_fireyellow:996440594199089182>';
        const omega1Emoji = '<:fendi_joeShush:996425564304986122>';

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('-------------------- •  ™       ')
            .setDescription('\n\n\n' +
                `${omegaEmoji} "- @ω"\n\n` +
                `${omega0Emoji} "- @ω₀"\n\n` +
                `${omega1Emoji} "- @ω₁"`);

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(omegaEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(omega0Emoji);
        messageEmbed.react(omega1Emoji);

        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji === omegaEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(omegaRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji === omega0Emoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(omega0Role);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji === omega1Emoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(omega1Role);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }

        });

        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async(reaction, user) => {

            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;


            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji === omegaEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(omegaRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji === omega0Emoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(omega0Role);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji === omega1Emoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(omega1Role);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method of getting custom emojis will not work like normal emojis, here's the difference:

- a normal emoji looks like this `:` `name` `:`
- Custom emoji looks like this `<` `:` `name` `:` `id` `>` (and if animated: `<` `a` `:` `name` `:` `id` `>`)

Custom emojis doesn't also have emoji.name property, or you will have to split`<:fendi_joeShush:996425564304986122>` to `:` `name` `:` to use it

```js
const split = omega1Emoji.split(':')
let emojiName = split[1]
emoji = <message>.guild.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => {
      return omegaEmoji.name === emojiName
})
```

You can use

```js
reaction.emoji.id === omega1Emoji.id
```

I recommend you using the id, it's easier and safer